# node-forge how to read a private rsa key from file

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa

This question is related to [Issue using RSA encryption in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893292/issue-using-rsa-encryption-in-javascript)

I have a node script that I am trying to read a PEM RSA private key from a file:

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let pkey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test.key'), 'utf8');
//let pkeyDer = forge.util.decode64(pkey); // since it's not base64 encoded, i suppose don't need to decode
let pkeyAsn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(pkey);
let privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromAsn1(pkeyAsn1);
```

The `test.key` file has a format like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
{mumbo jumbo line1}
{mumbo jumbo line2}
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I tried to import the file, the line fails at `pkeyAsn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(pkey);`, giving this error: 
  `Too few bytes to read ASN.1 value.`

I don't know too much about the file format, would somebody help me?

The private key file i generated is using the following openssl command: 
`openssl rsa -in encrypted_test.key -out test.key` and I entered my passphrase to decrypt such rsa key.

Comment: @dlongley  would you take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out. When reading a private key file, you must include the `---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---` and `---END RSA PRIVATE KEY---` banner.

Comment: I am facing same issue. My file has your mentioned banner also. What might be wrong

Answer (score 6):

Read pkey as bytes and use forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem.

Working code:

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let pkey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test.key'));
let privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(pkey);
```